# When I ssh into a specific server I get a interactive non-login shell. Why don't I get a login shell?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, login

So I found out my .profile or .bash_profile isn't sourced when I login via ssh.

I tried `shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'`

which gives me: `Not login shell` but if I start tmux it does give me a login shell.

Why?

EDIT: I connected using the command `ssh user@domain` using key authentication (Password authentication gives the same result.)
there are no relevant details in my .ssh/config file. (The same result without one.)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show how you're running ssh to connect to this system? Include any relevant entries from your .ssh/config file on the system that you connect from.

Comment: I wonder if your login shell on that server is invoking a subshell (via one of its initialization files). What is the result of `echo $SHLVL` after you log in?

Comment: Or some `ForceCommand` option in `sshd_config`.

Comment: echo $SHLVL gives 2 - sshd_config seems normal (No ForceCommand)

Comment: It matters _how_ you executed that `echo $SHLVL` command. Please update your question with the _exact_ commands you're using (e.g. if you're running stuff like `ssh remote 'somecommand'` or whether you are first logging in with `ssh remote` and then give commands in the shell that you get). Also mention what shell you are using on the remote system (`shopt` would fail in a non-bash shell, and you'd get "Not a login shell" for _that_ reason).

Comment: You're probably starting another bash shell from `/etc/profile` or some other script called from there. `SHLVL` should be 1 not 2 in a shell started directly from ssh.

Comment: Does `ps -Hf` show another process (other than your shell and `ps`)?

Comment: What does `ls -ld "$(getent passwd "$(logname)" | cut -d: -f7)"` give you? How about `printf '%s\n' "${SHELL-unset}"`?